# adding linear-gradient with MUI

Tags: css, next.js, material-ui

I need to add a linear-gradient using Material UI and couldn't
Can you help me to do that please?

I tried to read the MUI Docs, search on YouTube and ask chat-gpt, search on google and nothing of them worked .

the docs show me that i need to add it to theme using extendTheme but when i try to use it i can't because it is undefined
code :

```
import { extendTheme } from "@mui/joy/styles";
  extendTheme({
    colorSchemes: {
      light: {
        palette: {
          gradient: {
            instagram: "linear-gradient(to top,#c13584, #000)",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

// the component where i need to use it :
    <Typography
    variant="h6"
    sx={{
    fontSize: "12px",
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    width: "66px",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundImage: (theme) => 
    theme.vars.palette.gradient.instagram,
    }}>
    {item. User}
    enter code here</Typography>
```

[the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IwzX.png)
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRJI4.png)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question as text not images.

Comment: console.log your theme. I think you're using the wrong path to access the gradient as it's undefined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code as text and printed the theme.palette in the console and it doesn't have a gradient object

Comment: I solved the problem by creating new schema instead of adding the color to the existing one .